# django get_or_create with defaults parameter

Tags: django, dictionary, parameters

I have a syntax error with the following code:

```
ids_row={}
ids_row["releve_annee"]=int(row[0])
ids_row["releve_mois"]=int(row[1])
ids_row["no_ordre"]=int(row[2])
defaults={}
defaults["titre_rmc"]=row[3].strip()
defaults["notes"]=row[17].strip()
instance, created = Act.objects.get_or_create(**ids_row, defaults=defaults)
```

My model:

```
class Act(models.Model):
    releve_annee=models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=False, null=False)
    releve_mois=models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    no_ordre=models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    titre_rmc=models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=False, null=False)
    notes=models.CharField(max_length=2000,  blank=True, null=True, default=None)
        class Meta:
        unique_together=(("releve_annee", "releve_mois", "no_ordre"), )
```

In a shell:

```
instance, created = Act.objects.get_or_create(**ids_row, defaults=defaults)
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I remove `defaults=defaults`, the error disappears. What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing the sequence of parameters,

```
instance, created = Act.objects.get_or_create(defaults=defaults, **ids_row)
```

Comment: You cannot have any *args or **kwargs at the front of any function. Those always come at the end.

Comment: This is because the *args or **kwargs may vary in length, right?

Comment: @vabada It is part of the syntax